Is it possible to solve $\|X-A\|_2+\lambda_n\|X\|_1$?
After deeply understanding the lasso, I came up with an idea: could we get an estimator $\hat{X}$ with a spectral norm similar to the target matrix $A$? Adding the penalty term to get a sparse/low-rank estimator, I think this can be expressed as solving the following optimization problem
$$
\hat{X}=\underset{X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}{\operatorname{arg\,min}}\|X-A\|_2+\lambda_n\|X\|_1
$$
or
$$
\hat{X}=\underset{X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}{\operatorname{arg\,min}}\|X-A\|_2+\lambda_n\|X\|_{\text{nuclear}}.
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the spectral norm, $\|X\|_1=\underset{i,j}{\sum}|X_{ij}|$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\text{nuclear}}$ denotes the nuclear norm.
Has this problem been well studied? If so, what keywords should I use to find corresponding papers?

Equations 8, 9 of https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/mazumder10a/mazumder10a.pdf may be what you are looking for?

@DavidVeitch Equations 8&9 measure the similarity by Frobenius norm, but I want to use the spectral norm. Thanks a lot.

Equation 8 uses the nuclear norm (see line just below equation 2). Also take a look at proposition 1 and lemma 1 from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.03722. These papers both look at optimizing X with respect to A while controlling X's nuclear norm.

@DavidVeitch I have noticed that equation 8 uses the unclear norm as its penalty term, but what I am concerned about is the term $|X-A|_2$ where $|\cdot|_2$ denotes the spectral norm. The papers you mentioned use the Frobenius norm.

Yes my mistake, sorry about that.

This is reminiscent of low-rank matrix completion -- this work studies something similar-looking. While the proposed estimator uses the Frobenius norm, risk bounds for the spectral norm are shown in Section 5.3. If you really want to minimize spectral norm, there's textbooks that derive a constrained optimization formulation (e.g. pg. 169-70, Sec. 4.6.3).
